# Eclipse: choosing a default debugger for all new C projects

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Whenever I start a new project, I have to go through setting up the debugger with Eclipse time and time again before I can use it. Isn't there a default setting for all new C projects I can change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "setting up the debugger" (perhaps you can clarify), but under "Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Default Launchers" you should be able to select your preferred launcher for different kind of launch modes. This can also be selected individually for each launch configuration.

Typically it is up to the toolchain and/or project to determine which debugger/launcher is suitable to use for that specific project, but I know there is a bug in CDT which prevents toolchains from properly specifying the default launcher to use.

Answer (score 0):

I only use Eclipse for Java, so I can't give you an authoritative answer. But since no one else seems to be answering:

Java projects have a (more or less) hidden file in the project directory called `.project` and another one called `.settings` . I'm not sure if this would apply to the C environment as well, but it seems likely. You may want to look at the set of such "hidden" files for a well set up project and a virginal project side by side to find out which settings make the difference.

Given that information, you may be able to simply edit (perhaps with some assistance from a script you can write yourself) the file(s) in question to do the configuration textually without a lot of mouse clicking.